# Is f(x) = |sinx| + |cos x| differentiable at x = pi/2?

Tags: derivatives, continuity

I have proven that it is continuous at pi/2

For differentiability,
lim h-> 0 (f(x) - f(x-h))/ h = lim h-> 0 (|cos x| + |sinx| - |cos(x-h)| - |sin(x-h)|)/h

but I'm stuck after that.

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: I suggest using $x=\frac{\pi}2+u$  with $u\to 0$ and use the cos, sin formulas for a sum ads a first step. Then look at the sign of known limits $|\sin(u)|/u$ and $(|\cos(u)|-1)/u$.

Comment: No, because |cos(x)| is not differentiable at pi/2, but |sin(x)| is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $x\to\frac{\pi}{2}^-$, $|\sin x| = \sin x$ and $|\cos x| = \cos x$

For $x\to\frac{\pi}{2}^+$, $|\sin x| = \sin x$ and $|\cos x| = -\cos x$

---

$\begin{align}RHD &= \lim_{x\to\frac{\pi}{2}^+}\frac{f(x) - f(\frac{\pi}{2})}{x-\frac{\pi}{2}}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(\frac{\pi}{2}+h)-f(\frac{\pi}{2}) }{h}\end{align}$

Now for $x\to\frac{\pi}{2}^+$$|\sin x| = \sin x$ and $|\cos x| = -\cos x$

So,

$\begin{align}RHD &= \lim_{h\to0}\frac{\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}+h)-\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}+h)-1}{h} = \lim_{h\to0}\frac{\cos(h)+\sin(h)-1}{h}\\&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\cos(h)-1}{h}+\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\sin(h)}{h}=0+1 = 1\end{align} $

Similarly find, $LHD$. Check if it's equal to $RHD$

Comment: The wording states differentiable at a point, so proving $f'$ is discontinuous won't help. You have to go for $f(x)-f(x_0)/(x-x_0)$.

Comment: I'm not sure how to proceed with the computation of the derivatives. I have (|cos x| + |sinx| - |cos(x-h)| - |sin(x-h)|)/h but don't know how to proceed further.

Comment: @user1742188. Edited post....

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution by examining the function in the specific intervals of where $x \in [0,\pi]$.

Suppose:
$f(x)=|cos x|+|sin x| \quad x \in [0, \pi]$

$f_1(x)=cosx + sinx \; \forall \; x \in [0, \pi/2]$

$f_2(x)=-cosx + sinx \; \forall \; x \in [\pi/2, \pi]$

$f_1^{'}(x)=-sinx+cosx$

$f_2^{'}(x)=sinx+cosx$

At $x=\pi/2$ ; $f_1^{'}(x)=f_2^{'}(x)$

But:

$f_1^{'}(\pi/2)=-1$ And $f_2^{'}(\pi/2)=1$

Hence, $f(x)$ is not differentiable at $\pi/2$